# Div CSS Background color in Safari 8

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm "reapairing the website that someone else made.
Everything is showing up fine on firefox and chrome, but somehow on Safari 8 the #obiekty-taby div css is totally crashed. Background color, padding, font css. (Encoding is crashed, but I've got it covered)

[Website](http://davebream.kei.pl/sun-seasons-lifting/karpacz/)

I'm asking for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your css crashed in Safari. make sure your all plugins working

Comment: by plugins you mean safari plugins or plugins installed on the website?

Comment: I turned off all js and the problem still occurs. One of the files is a problem. If I copy the CSS code to another css file - everything works.

Comment: I've found an unclosed css statement.